# Getting overflow y auto to work within nested flex boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css, overflow

I am losing the battle to what seems like a pretty simple layout and for the life of me I cannot figure out why the behavior I'm seeing is happening (even Chat GPT hasn't given solutions that work).

I have a layout which includes a top menu, a left sidebar, and a main container (which is broken into a top container and bottom container like so)

[image]

My goal is to get the container filled with 'hi' to NOT push the bottom bar down as it fills up and instead start scrolling without moving the sizes of the containers at all. This is what it looks like if I double the amount of 'hi's in the text area

[image]

As you can see, the bottom bar has vanished, and while the hi container does scroll when I reach the bottom, the bottom bar still isn't visible.

Does anyone have any idea what I need to do to fix this so it works as I'd expect it to? I have run into immense trouble getting `overflow-y-auto` to work within flex boxes so I must be lacking some core understanding of how it all works. Here is a link to Tailwind Play so anyone who wants to quickly give it a try can check it out:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/JAiaaCsR6M

Thank you for checking it out!

Answer (score 1):

Consider applying `min-height: 0` via the `min-h-0` class to the container element. This overrides the implicit `min-height: min-content` applied by the parent vertical flex layout container.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.0"></script>

<div class="w-screen h-screen max-w-full max-h-full overflow-hidden flex flex-col border">
  <div id="top-nav" style="height: 50px" class="flex w-full border items-center justify-center">top nav</div>
  <div class="flex grow min-h-0">
    <div id="sidebar" class="flex basis-1/6 w-full border border-orange items-center justify-center">sidebar</div>
    <div id="content-container" class="flex flex-col basis-5/6 border items-center justify-center overflow-hidden">
      <div class="flex-grow overflow-y-auto w-full" id="scrollable-container">
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>hi</p>
        
        <!-- add more ps here to see it push the bottom bar down -->
      </div>
      <div class="flex basis-1/5 border w-full">bottom bar</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that solution is working but im not sure i understand why. who is setting min-height: min-content and why does that being set prevent the nested children from adhering to max-h-full + overflow-y-auto?

Comment: `min-height: min-content` is applied by the parent vertical flex layout container. It does not prevent the nested children from adhering to `max-h-full` + `overflow-y-auto`. Rather, `min-height: min-content` would make the element be the height of its content, thus no overflow occurs within it for scrolling to be possible.